# Why does this code look different on major browsers?

Tags: html, css, browser

I tried to use flexbox to create an image with a caption, where the caption has the same width as the image and where image and caption have a size relative to the viewport height.

```html
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .container {
            background-color: red;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            height: 100%;
            width: min-content;
            text-align: center;
            align-items: center;
        }
        .top {
            background: blue;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .toptop {
        }
        img {
            height: 100%;            
            max-width: 80vw;
            background: green;
            object-fit: contain;
        }
        .bottom {
            flex:1;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="top">
            <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/228/400/600.jpg?hmac=6cBQvjod0l8LDO2YShbpq_Yoiyd9bOC0xj_maEUkkg0">
        </div>
        <div class="bottom">
            caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption caption 
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please have a look at the image to see how different it looks on the 3 major browsers: [Safari, Firefox, Chrome - same viewport dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBkZy.png)

Or check the code in your browser:

- [plain code](https://imgoverlay.intergestalt.monster/img-overlay5.html)
- [with vendor prefixes and reset](https://imgoverlay.intergestalt.monster/img-overlay5_reset_prefixed.html)

Comment: you have to learn about css reset

Comment: this is because "browser prefixes styles". you can easily use: prefixier to automatically add CSS prefix class name to solve this.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not about prefixing nor about resets.

Comment: Check this version with vendor prefixes and eric meyer reset: https://imgoverlay.intergestalt.monster/img-overlay5_reset_prefixed.html

Comment: I assume that it has to do with the way the flex box layout and image sizing play into another.  Chrome interprets "height: 100%" as 100% of the whole container, rather than 100% of the actual parent ".top". Safari too, but crops. Firefox doesn't.